# How to check datatable select method returns datatable c#

Tags: c#, datatable

How to check datatable select method returns datatable or not c#

e.g

```
   datatable _dtt= dt.Select("fcm_id=1").CopyToDataTable();
```

above statement return all rows if fcm_id is 1 if datatable didn't have any row its throwing exception ....how to validate its row or not

e.g 
    if(_dtt.Rows.Count > 0)

thank you

Comment: what exception is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using ternary operator to check if count is greater than 0 then call `CopyToDataTable()` else return empty `DataTable` or `null`:

```
DataTable _dtt = dt.Select("fcm_id=1").Count() > 0 ? dt.Select("fcm_id=1").CopyToDataTable() :new DataTable();
```

or do with normal `if`:

```
var result = dt.Select("fcm_id=1");

DataTable _dtt =null;

if (result.Count() > 0)
    _dtt = result.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to assign the select result to DataRow array and check the length of the array and then assign the array to the DataTable using CopyToDataTable().

```
DataTable _dtt = new DataTable();
DataRow[] dr = _dtt.Select("fcm_id=1");//assign the result of select() to datarow array 
if (dr.Length > 0)//check if select() returns any data
   _dtt = dr.CopyToDataTable(); //copy the rows of data to the datatable
```